# embedded video in Safari on iOS

Tags: ios, video, safari

I put the following code in html and tried to watch the video on my iPad. It worked.

```
<object width="425" height="355">
  <param name="movie"
         value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3&autohide=1&showinfo=0"></param>
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3&autohide=1&showinfo=0"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         allowscriptaccess="always"
         width="425" height="355"></embed>
</object>
```

I realize this code is for flash player but I could watch it on iOS.

Does anybody tell me what's going on about this and is this a legal way to show videos on iOS?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely working because Apple has integrated YouTube links into the OS a little.

The recommended way is to use [HTML5's `video` tag](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html).

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I understood iOS does something special for YouTube links when I tried Yahoo Video which didn't work.